# Character issue in exact target subscriber full name

Tags: php, marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

When I am added the attribute in to subscriber show the below character issue.

I have used the code php fuel sdk.[image]

Comment: Are you submitting the data as UTF-8? Is the source string in UTF-8? A "?" means that the character isn't valid in the current character set.

Answer (score 1):

ExactTarget allows for International sending which is documented [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/international_sends/)

The following language encodings are supported by ExactTarget :

- Big5 - Chinese (Traditional)
- EUC-KR  - Korean
- GB2312 - Chinese (Simplified)
- ISO-8859-1 - Western European: Danish, Dutch (partial),
  English, Faeroese, Finnish (partial), French (partial), German,
  Icelandic,Irish, Italian, Norwegian, Portuguese, Rhaeto-Romanic,
  Scottish Gaelic, Spanish, and Swedish. Also: Albanian, Indonesian,
  Afrikaans and Swahili.
- ISO-8859-2 - Central European: Bosnian,
  Polish, Croatian, Czech, Slovak, Slovenian, and Hungarian.
- ISO-2022-JP - Japanese
- KOI8-R - Russian, Bulgarian
- Shift-JIS - Japanese
- UTF-8 (Unicode) - Most languages, gaining universal
  acceptance in most areas of the world
- US-ASCII - English: United
  States (ExactTarget default for non-International emails)

This section here - http://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/technical_library/web_service_guide/working_with_soap_web_service_api#section_24 explains how to send International emails with the API.  You should be able to work these objects into your SDK calls fairly easily.

Comment: Please give me format of UTF-8.                              I have used below code for insert the attribute for subscriber.                                         $subscriber = new ET_Subscriber();
$subscriber->authStub = $client; 
$subscriber->props = array("EmailAddress" => "YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_GOES_HERE", "Lists" => array("ID" => "YOUR_LIST_ID_GOES_HERE")); 
$subscriber->props['Attributes'] = array(array('Name' => 'FirstName', 'Value' => 'YOUR_FIRST_NAME_GOES_HERE')); 
$response = $subscriber->post(); 
print_r($response);